# How to select one object each from django distinct queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Suppose

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, ...)
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    ...
```

```
class SavedPosts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(...)
    post = models.ForiegnKey(Post, ...)
    collection_name = models.CharField(...)
```

I am getting colection names using

```
SavedPosts.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values("collection_name").distinct().order_by('collection_name')
```

How do i get image of post from that collection?
Just like instagram do.
Can it be done without creating seperate model for collection?

Comment: now that you have the distinct list of collections, create a query with `SavedPosts.objects.filter(collection_name__in=my_distinct_list_of_collections)`

Comment: You may need to flatten your original values collection using values_list with the `flat=True` parameter. I forget if the values queryset can be used directly in the way I suggested.

Comment: All i am getting is list of collection names or list of images. That not what i want. I want one image from any post of that collection and for every collection of user

Comment: What does your post model look like (edit your question to add that)

Comment: Done editing. Check now